# WSL not working after moving Ubuntu from C: to D:

Tags: ubuntu, powershell, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I needed to move some files from my SSD (C:) to my HDD (D:), so I used the move option on the Ubuntu app listed in Settings>Apps>Installed Apps. However, this stopped WSL from recognizing that I had Ubuntu installed, even after I moved it back to the C: drive.

After uninstalling and reinstalling Ubuntu through both Powershell or Microsoft Store, I get the following error message:

```
Failed to attach disk 'C:\Users\sukes\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx' to WSL2: The system cannot find the file specified.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/MountVhd/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Failed to attach disk 'C:\Users\sukes\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx' to WSL2: The system cannot find the file specified.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/MountVhd/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Failed to attach disk 'C:\Users\sukes\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx' to WSL2: The system cannot find the file specified.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/MountVhd/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Press any key to continue...
```

What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Copy the vhdx, uninstall Ubuntu then reinstall Ubuntu in its new location. This will create a new instance of WSL Ubuntu. Once working replace the new vhdx with the original file in its new location

Comment: If you cannot find the file then it was deleted by the migration. Why, would be unclear.